# Ctrl-Left/Right not working for multiple cursors on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure where to ask this question, but yesterday, if I added a cursor to an above/below line (`Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down`), I was able to move both to the start of the word if I did `Ctrl-Left/Right`, or select both with `Ctrl-Shift-Left/Right`.

However, today, if I have multiple cursors, and try `Ctrl-Left/Right` or `Ctrl-Shift-Left/Right`, all my other cursors disappear. How do I fix this issue?

Note: My other cursors do not disappear if I do `Shift-Left/Right` or just `Left/Right`

Default Keybindings .json

```
[
    { 
        "key": "ctrl+right",            
        "command": "cursorWordEndRight",
        "when": "textInputFocus && !accessibilityModeEnabled" 
    },
   {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+right",      
        "command": "cursorWordEndRightSelect",
        "when": "textInputFocus && !accessibilityModeEnabled"
    },
   {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+up",           
        "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
        "when": "editorTextFocus" 
    },
```

Comment: I can't replicate in Stable or Insiders.  So you should check for conflicting keybindings.  For instance, what do you get in the Keyboard Shortcuts window when you select the Recording Keys icon (the little keyboard icon to the right) and type Ctrl+left?  Does `cursorLeft` show up as a command and is there anything else that might interfere with tha?  You can also start the command to `Toggle KeyboardShortcuts Troubleshooting` and see what Ctrl+Left resolves to.

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

Change

```
"when": "textInputFocus && !accessibilityModeEnabled"
```

to

```
"when": "editorTextFocus"
```